# It does not show the detail of the data I pulled from the database with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I pull data from the database, but it does not show this data.

```
    [
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
    ]
```

My code is as follows.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Repository\PlayerRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class hello extends AbstractController
{

    /**
     * @Route("/hello", name="hello")
     */
    public function club(PlayerRepository $playerRepository)
    {
        return $this->json($playerRepository->findAll());
    }
}
```

There is no problem when I open a different project and try it. But I cannot do this because I have progressed a bit in the project.

My Player Entity Class is as follows :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\PlayerRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="player")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=PlayerRepository::class)
 */
class Player
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="country_id", type="integer")
     */
    private $countryId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="player_no", type="integer")
     */
    private $playerNo;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="nick_name" ,type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nickName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="middle_name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $middleName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="last_name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $lastName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="gender", type="string", length=10)
     */
    private $gender;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="length", type="integer")
     */
    private $length;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="birth_date", type="datetime")
     */
    private $birthDate;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="birth_place", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $birthPlace;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="strong_foot", type="string", length=10)
     */
    private $strongFoot;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getCountryId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->countryId;
    }

    public function setCountryId(int $countryId): self
    {
        $this->countryId = $countryId;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPlayerNo(): ?int
    {
        return $this->playerNo;
    }

    public function setPlayerNo(int $playerNo): self
    {
        $this->playerNo = $playerNo;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNickName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nickName;
    }

    public function setNickName(string $nickName): self
    {
        $this->nickName = $nickName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFirstName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    public function setFirstName(string $firstName): self
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMiddleName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->middleName;
    }

    public function setMiddleName(?string $middleName): self
    {
        $this->middleName = $middleName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    public function setLastName(string $lastName): self
    {
        $this->lastName = $lastName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getGender(): ?string
    {
        return $this->gender;
    }

    public function setGender(string $gender): self
    {
        $this->gender = $gender;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLength(): ?int
    {
        return $this->length;
    }

    public function setLength(int $length): self
    {
        $this->length = $length;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getBirthDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->birthDate;
    }

    public function setBirthDate(\DateTimeInterface $birthDate): self
    {
        $this->birthDate = $birthDate;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getBirthPlace(): ?string
    {
        return $this->birthPlace;
    }

    public function setBirthPlace(string $birthPlace): self
    {
        $this->birthPlace = $birthPlace;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStrongFoot(): ?string
    {
        return $this->strongFoot;
    }

    public function setStrongFoot(string $strongFoot): self
    {
        $this->strongFoot = $strongFoot;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

The problem is solved in the comments section.

Comment: Please show us your `Player` entity

Comment: I added to the comments section. and also this happens in all my tables. It's not just Player.

Comment: Okay. Have you installed the serializer component? See https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html

Comment: when `$this->json(...)` is used, it's first checked if the object(s) implements [JsonSerializable](https://php.net/JsonSerializable), and if they don't, the public (!) properties are serialized. Since most entities by default make all properties private, the common serialization of an entity is `{}`. So either you use proper Serialization like the Serializer Philip Weinke mentioned or you implement the mentioned interface on your entities (which one to choose really depends on your use case). also the "comments section" you posted the code to is the answer section and thus misplaced

Comment: Yes it worked. Thank you so much. Thank you in the explanation. I joined the site today, I'm sorry I don't know exactly how to use it.

Comment: Hi Furkan - Welcome to the site. Please update your original question (click 'edit' at the bottom), and add the additional file as additional information in the edited question, then delete the extra answer.  After that, please post the information on how to solve this issue as a new answer, if another answer hasn't been posted. That will help anyone in the future who had the same issue.  Thanks!